# Price filter with input using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

i used below code to filter product with `jquery` slider and i want to replace **Slider** with **Input**.

and tried with bellow code but it doesn't work, Can some one help me to solve what am doing wrong. since i use **radio** and **checkbox** to filter product so i don't want to replace code instead by doing modification how can i achieve price filter

**HTML**

```
<input type="input" id="minimum_price" class="form-control" name="min_price"> 
<input type="input" id="maximum_price" class="form-control" name="max_price">
<input type="submit">

$(document).ready(function () {
            filter_data();
            function filter_data() {
                $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
                var action = 'fetch_data';
                var minimum_price = $('#minimum_price').val();
                var maximum_price = $('#maximum_price').val();
                var brand = get_filter('brand');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "fetch.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {action: action, minimum_price: minimum_price, maximum_price: maximum_price, brand:brand},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.filter_data').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            function get_filter(class_name) {
                var filter = [];
                $('.' + class_name + ':checked').each(function () {
                    filter.push($(this).val());
                });
                return filter;
            }
            $('.common_selector').click(function () {
                filter_data();
            });
        });
```

**Fetch.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_status = '1'";

    if(isset($_POST["minimum_price"], $_POST["maximum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["minimum_price"]) && !empty($_POST["maximum_price"]))
    {
        $query .= " AND product_price BETWEEN '".$_POST["minimum_price"]."' AND '".$_POST["maximum_price"]."'
        ";
    }
```

Comment: explain "doesn't work" please

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia it doesn't trigger and price filter the query remains same when i enter price.

Comment: @sanoj lawrence Did you solve it? Because i have the same problem.

Comment: @Mantykora7 i had other issue in this question, share your code in github let me try to solve your problem :)